# expo and firestore, unhandled promise rejection: typeError

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I have been getting this error for the last two days now.
This happened after I installed a node module named "faker". What I've found out until now is that npm 5 deleted any packages from the package.lock.json that were not installed using npm 5.
Hence I deleted node modules and the package.lock.json and did an npm install, it didn't help.
I created a separate expo project and copied the files over to it from the old project and installed every module again, it still does not work.

Below is the error I am getting:

```
[15:18:35] [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'collection[typeof Symbol === "function" ? Symbol.iterator : "@@iterator"]()')]
- node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:8293:17 in forEach
- node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:13322:42 in onTransactionCommitted
- ... 52 more stack frames from framework internals
```